# Removing pattern from multiple lines using sed or awk in two places in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, jq

I have a JSON file with 12,166,466 of lines. 
I want to remove quotes from values on keys: 
`"timestamp": "1538564256",`and `"score": "10",` to look like
`"timestamp": 1538564256,` and `"score": 10,`.

Input:

```
{
    "title": "DNS domain", ,
    "timestamp": "1538564256",
    "domain": {
        "dns": [
            "www.google.com"
        ]
    },
    "score": "10",
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa"
    "id": "c-1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
}, {
    "title": "DNS domain",
    "timestamp": "1538564256",
    "domain": {
        "dns": [
            "google.de"
        ]
    },
    "score": "10",
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa",
    "id": "du1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
}
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "title": "DNS domain", ,
    "timestamp": 1538564256,
    "domain": {
        "dns": [
            "www.google.com"
        ]
    },
    "score": 10,
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa"
    "id": "c-1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
}, {
    "title": "DNS domain",
    "timestamp": 1538564256,
    "domain": {
        "dns": [
            "google.de"
        ]
    },
    **"score": 10,**
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa",
    "id": "du1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
}
}
```

I have tried:

```
sed -E '
s/"timestamp": "/"timestamp": /g
s/"score": "/"score": /g
'
```

the first part is quite straightforward, but how to remove ", at that the end of the line that contains "timestamp" and "score"? How do I access that using sed or even awk, or other tool with the mind that I have 12 million lines to process?

Comment: Instead of parsing it yourself using sed or awk, isn't there some JSON parsing tool you might use?

Comment: The JSON itself was produced using JQ. I believe there is no way to tell JQ not to do double quotes about certain fields.

Comment: What about [`tonumber`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber) ?

Comment: I will have a look at this command, I was not aware of it.

Comment: I wouldn't try something like that: `sed -E 's/: "([0-9]+)"/: \1/' file`

Comment: If the JSON is (at least in principle) produced by [jq] then it should be possible to fix your sample so that it is valid JSON. Please do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you fix your JSON input file like this:

```
<file jq .
[
  {
    "title": "DNS domain",
    "timestamp": "1538564256",
    "domain": {
      "dns": [
        "www.google.com"
      ]
    },
    "score": "10",
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa",
    "id": "c-1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
  },
  {
    "title": "DNS domain",
    "timestamp": "1538564256",
    "domain": {
      "dns": [
        "google.de"
      ]
    },
    "score": "10",
    "link": "www.bit.ky/sdasd/asddsa",
    "id": "du1eOWYB9XD0VZRJuWL6"
  }
]
```

You can use `jq` and its `tonumber` function to change the wanted strings to values:

```
<file jq '.[].timestamp |= tonumber | .[].score |= tonumber'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON structure matches roughly your example (e. g., there won't be any other whitespace characters between `"timestamp"`, the colon, and the value), then this awk should be ok. If available, using `jq` for JSON transformation is the better choice by far!

```
awk '{print gensub(/("(timestamp|score)": )"([0-9]+)"/, "\\1\\3", "g")}' file
```

Comment: I think you mean something like: `awk '{print gensub(/"(timestamp|score)": "([0-9]+)"/, "\"\\1\": \\2", "g")}'`

Comment: @peak Oh, yes, I missed the parentheses around `timestamp|score`, thanks! But I find a direct downvote a little harsh :-(

Comment: Since the OP says the JSON comes from jq, I believe the parsing in this case can be 100% accurate with a small awk program.  If you can reformulate the caveat accurately, I'll upvote :-)

Comment: @peak Well, look at the JSON, it's actually syntactically incorrect ;-) (there at least three errors)

Answer (score 1):

1. Be warned that `tonumber` can lose precision.  If using `tonumber` is inadmissible, and if the output is produced by jq (or otherwise linearized vertically), then using awk as proposed elsewhere on this page is a good way to go.  (If your awk does not have gensub, then the awk program can be easily adapted.) Here is the same thing using `sed`, assuming its flag for extended regex processing is `-E`:

   `sed -E -e 's/"(timestamp|score)": "([0-9]+)"/"\1": \2/'`
2. For reference, if there's any doubt about where the relevant keys are located, here's a filter in jq that is agnostic about that:

   `walk(if type == "object" 
        then if has("timestamp") then .timestamp|=tonumber else . end
        | if has("score") then .score|=tonumber else end 
        else . end)`

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then simply snarf its def from the web, e.g. from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq

3. If you wanted to convert all number-valued strings to numbers, you could write:

   `walk(if type=="object" then map_values(tonumber? // .) else . end)`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/"timestamp":\s*"1538564256",/{s/"//3g;:b;n;/timestamp/ba;/"score":\s*"10"/s/"//3g;Tb}' file
```

On encountering a line that contains `"timestamp": "1538564256",` remove the 3rd or more `"`'s. Then read on until another line containing `timestamp` and repeat or a line containing `"score": "10` and remove the 3rd or more `"`'s.